# Visual Studio reports fake schema validation errors. How to clean SharePoint schema cache?

Tags: development, visual-studio, caml-query

I have recently generated a couple of ListDefinitions using both [SPSource](http://spsource.codeplex.com) and VSeWSS SharePoint Solution Generator. In both cases, surpisingly, Visual Studio reports fake schema validation errors in schema.xml like

> The 'Description' attribute is not declared" for List xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/" BaseType="0" DefaultItemOpen="0" Description=""... >...

followed by errors like

> Could not find schema information for the element 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/:GetVar'.

Can anyone help me fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me. They weren't fake. Some of the exported attributes really break the schema and only get generated after the solution being deployed and activated.